# TPL Task scheduled to run on UI thread vs UI Thread

Tags: task-parallel-library

What is the difference between code running in a task, scheduled to run on synchronization context of the UI thread vs code running directly on a message pump.

I've noticed a number of behavioural differences.

Comment: Can you give some sample code, and examples of what you've already noticed?

Comment: 1) If somewhere along the line of running that "UI" task it calls TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() to be used to create another Task. That new task doesn't run on UI thread.

Comment: 2) If System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync() executed from "UI" task then its RunWorkerCompleted event isn't raised on UI thread.

Comment: That's not the behavior I observe. Tasks that run using `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` act as UI thread normally would: new Task that uses the same is also scheduled on the UI thread and RunWorkerCompleted is raised on the UI thread. Could you show us your code that shows the issues? There's probably something wrong with it.

Comment: I can't reproduce this behaviour in a simple application. I saw it only in a very big Winform application with DevExpress controls. Inside that "ContinueWith" UI scheduled task it closed several windows, then opened another until it started this BackgroundWorker. RunWorkerCompleted always resulted on a worker thread... The workaround to that was to replace that UI Task with Control.BeginInvoke.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by "code running directly on a message pump", but looking at the reference source, you can see that basically

`WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.Send` = `Control.Invoke`
`WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.Post` = `Control.BeginInvoke`
`DispatcherSynchronizationContext.Send` = `Dispatcher.Invoke`
`DispatcherSynchronizationContext.Post` = `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`

So when the task scheduler schedules a task on the UI thread it should be equivalent to you doing so

Comment: I guess if you call for example TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() from inside UI Task it doesn't really know if it's WinForm or Dispatcher does it? Probably it just returns default SynchronizationContext...

Comment: `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` uses `SynchronizationContext.Current`, which in turn takes it from the currently running thread: `Thread.CurrentThread.GetExecutionContextNoCreate().SynchronizationContext`